# How to fit mm/yyyy in SUMIF criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I've looked around for answers regarding this, but am still a bit confused. I have a column A in Excel with dates in the format mm-yyyy (i.e. September 1014 is Sep-14). I want to add all the values in column H that fall in a particular month and year. 
So for example, I want to add all values that in Sep-2014. I'm trying to do this using SUMIF, but I don't know how to format the criteria. I have seen solutions advising to use an array...is there another, simpler way to do this?
The dates are formatted in Excel and I have manually added them. I just don't want a large formula since I might be using this quite a bit in my spreadsheet and Excel tends to lag when file size is large on my computer.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than a `SUMIF` with one criteria, use `SUMIFS` so you can specify two criteria.

So you simply need to sum everything in column H where the value in column A is equal to, or after 1st September, AND before 1st October.

```
=SUMIFS(H:H,A:A,">=01/09/2014",A:A,"<01/10/2014")
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `SUMPRODUCT` and use `MONTH` and `YEAR` to establish conditions for inclusion in the sum.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$10)=9)*(YEAR($A$1:$A$10)=2014),$H$1:$H$10)
```

This checks for the month being September and the year being 2014.

Comment: Andi's method worked, but I'll keep this in mind. Thank you!